# How do you print an attribute of a subclass?

Tags: python, class, printing

I am making a text based game and this is the file I am using to establishing the attributes of the rooms. Whenever I try to test this file out by printing the room description of room3 (print Room3.desc) I receive the error: AttributeError: type object 'Room3' has no attribute 'desc'

```
  class Room:
    def __init__(self, x, y, desc):
        self.x=x
        self.y=y
        self.desc=desc



class Room1(Room):
    def __init__(self, x, y, desc):
        super(Room1, self).__init__()
        self.x=0
        self.y=0
        self.desc="""

        A Metal Hallway
        This place is dimly lit and cool
        ----------------------------------------------------
        You stand in the middle of an intersection in a metal room.
        There are blue glowing lamps lighting this area up. There
        is a sign on the wall.
        ----------------------------------------------------
        Obvious exits:East, North"""

class Room2(Room):
    def __init__(self, x, y, desc):
        super(Room2, self).__init__()
        self.x=1
        self.y=0
        self.desc="""

        Thacker's Main Control Room
        This place is well lit and cool
        ----------------------------------------------------
        There are multiple panels throughout with a variety of levers and buttons.
        People stand in uniforms infront of computers, which are scattered throughout the room.
        There is a glass window here revealing space.
        Thacker is sitting here in the back of the room in a large chair.
        ----------------------------------------------------
        Obvious exits:West"""

class Room3(Room):
    def __init__(self, x, y, desc):
        super(Room3, self).__init__()
        self.x=0
        self.y=1
        self.desc== """


        Large Hanger Bay
        This place is well lit and cool
        ----------------------------------------------------
        There are a variety of mobile suits here
        ----------------------------------------------------
        Obvious exits:South"""


print("%s" % Room3.desc)
```

Answer (score 2):

You're trying to access `desc` via reference to the class itself, but desc is defined in the constructor, which means it's only available in *instances* of the class.

This points to a general problem with your code: you're defining subclasses of Room, when what you really want is to create instances of the class Room:

```
room1 = Room(0, 0, """A Metal Hallway...")
room2 = Room(1, 0, """Thacker's main control room...")
etc...
```

Comment: Will knows what hes talking about. The way you are doing it, you are making a room room, which is not what you want. You want to make room objects like `room1= Room(0,0,'''bla''')` and then once you have that, then you can start calling .desc, like you were doing `room1.desc, room2.desc, etc`

Comment: Thanks! You clarified for me, appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

Your `__init__` methods define attributes of instances, not of classes.  If you had something like this:

```
class Room3(Room):
  desc = 'foo'
  ...
```

Then there would be such a thing as `Room3.desc`.  As it is, you would need something like this:

```
r = Room3(x, y, 'foo')
print(r.desc)
```

For more, study the tutorial, the section on Classes, at [docs.python.org](http://docs.python.org).

Answer (score 1):

Room3.desc is an *instance* attribute rather than a *class* attribute.  You can't access instance attributes on a class object - they don't exist there.

You aren't using an instance of Room3, but the class, so you can't access the attribute that doesn't exist.  You *can* create a throwaway instance if you want to access the default instance attribute:

```
print Room3(None, None, None).desc
```

Also, your calls to your superclass **init** methods will fail in instance construction, because you aren't passing required arguments.

Answer (score 1):

As `cmd` says, `desc` is not an attribute of the `Room3` class object, it's an attribute of each `Room3` *instance*.

I think the *real* problem here is that you don't want `Room3` to be a subclass of `Room`; you just want an *instance* of `Room`. There's no code or attributes specific to `Room3`, and it's hard to imagine you're going to be creating a bunch of `Room3` instances.

So what you probably want is this:

```
room3 = Room(1, 0, """blah blah""")
```

Now you can `print room3.desc` and it will work fine.

---

Meanwhile, if you *do* want `Room3` to be a class, there are a lot of problems with your design:

```
def __init__(self, x, y, desc):
    super(Room3, self).__init__()
    self.x=0
    self.y=1
    self.desc== """…"""
```

First, that `super` call is going to raise an exception, because `Room.__init__` takes `x`, `y`, and `desc` parameters, and you aren't passing them. You have to change it to `super(Room3, self).__init__(x, y, desc)`.

But once you fix that, the base class is going to set `self.x`, etc., just for you to immediately replace them with new values. Why do this? And why even *take* `x`, `y`, and `desc` parameters just to ignore them?

I think what you want is this:

```
def __init__(self):
    super(Room3, self).__init__(0, 1, """…""")
```

This is actually a pretty common pattern (although not as common as in languages like C++ and Java), where you have a base class that holds some variables that can take arbitrary values, and subclasses that have specific values for some of those variables.

But, as I said, I don't think it's the pattern you want here. I think you just want a `room3` instance of `Room`, not a subclass.

---

Finally, to answer the question you directly asked, "How do you print an attribute of a subclass?", that's easy. Just print it. That's how duck typing works. For example:

```
class Base(object):
    def print_x(self):
        print self.x

class Derived(Base):
    def __init__(self, x):
        self.x = x

base = Derived(3)
base.print_x()
```

Answer (score 1):

`print("%s" % Room3.desc)`

`desc` is an attribute of an instance of Room3, not of class Room3 itself. If you instanciate Room3, then you can access its attribute desc. Also be careful with your `__init()__` as you have an extra `=`

```
class Room3(Room):
    def __init__(self, x, y, desc):
        super(Room3, self).__init__()
        self.x=0
        self.y=1
        self.desc== """
```

last line should be `self.desc= """`

Answer (score 0):

`Room3` class does not have the attribute `desc`. Instances of that class do.  So something like this would work:

```
room3 = Room3()
print(room3.desc)
```

Answer (score -1):

`self.desc== """`

There is an extra `=`. And you must instantiate `Room3` to access the `desc` attribute.

Comment: good point, missed the extra `=` the assignment should be `self.desc = """` not `self.desc== """`